# should I know what exactly happens inside a Bootstrap 3/4 class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been learning Bootstrap 3 for 4 days, and before that I had never used a framework, so I don't know how much I should know about it.

I've learned how to use some Bootstrap classes for a specific objective, for example:

Use some classes to style buttons

```
      <button class="btn btn-success active">Click me</button>

      <button class="btn btn-success">Click me</button>
```

My question is: should I know exactly what happens inside the classes or should I just know how to use it and how to change something in case I need to?

Comment: depends on the context or logic which you are implementing. But, most cases, you will not need to dig deep inside the framework.

Comment: Yes, the general principle that you should know what a tool does if you are going to be using it applies to *all* tools, including CSS libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Dear the more your explore the more you learn about the structure and styling of bootstrap framework.

For the startup you just need to know what these classes actually do and late on find out how these classes works and last but not least how to override theses style as per requirement.

Just remember learning never ends! Cheers

Always use Framework's official guideline for startup.
[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)